# Unorderable types when creating a child object in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I'm using SQLAlchemy as my ORM in a web app. When I try to create a new object and add it as a child of some other object, I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1346, in _execute
    result = method(*self.path_args, **self.path_kwargs)
File "/usr/share/app/server/handlers.py", line 248, in wrapper
    return fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/share/app/server/crud/node.py", line 157, in post
    session.flush()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2004, in flush
    self._flush(objects)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2122, in _flush
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 60, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 182, in reraise
    raise value
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2086, in _flush
    flush_context.execute()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 373, in execute
    rec.execute(self)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/unitofwork.py", line 532, in execute
    uow
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 149, in save_obj
    base_mapper, states, uowtransaction
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 270, in _organize_states_for_save
    states):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1035, in _connections_for_states
    for state in _sort_states(states):
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1057, in _sort_states
    sorted(persistent, key=lambda q: q.key[1])
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < UUID()
```

The primary keys are composed of two UUIDs (like multitenancy). I'm using `sqlalchemy.ext.orderinglist` to order the children, with an integer `seq` column to store the indices. The code for creating the new object is roughly:

```
node = Node(group_id=group_id)
hierarchy = (session.query(Hierarchy).get((hierarchy_id, group_id)))
node.hierarchy = hierarchy
hierarchy.nodes.append(node)
hierarchy.nodes.reorder()
session.flush()
```

For completeness, here are the relevant mappings and relationships:

```
class Group(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'group'
    id = Column(GUID, default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)

class Hierarchy(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'hierarchy'
    id = Column(GUID, default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    group_id = Column(
        GUID, ForeignKey('group.id'), nullable=False, primary_key=True)

class Node(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'node'
    id = Column(GUID, default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    group_id = Column(GUID, nullable=False, primary_key=True)
    hierarchy_id = Column(GUID, nullable=False)
    parent_id = Column(GUID)
    seq = Column(Integer)

    __table_args__ = (
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['parent_id', 'group_id'],
            ['node.id', 'node.group_id']
        ),
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['hierarchy_id', 'group_id'],
            ['hierarchy.id', 'hierarchy.group_id']
        ),
        ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['group_id'],
            ['group.id']
        ),
    )

    group = relationship(Group)

Group.hierarchies = relationship(
    Hierarchy, backref="group", passive_deletes=True,
    order_by='Hierarchy.title')

Hierarchy.nodes_all = relationship(
    Node, backref='hierarchy', passive_deletes=True,
    primaryjoin=and_(foreign(Node.hierarchy_id) == Hierarchy.id,
                    Node.group_id == Hierarchy.group_id))

Hierarchy.nodes = relationship(
    Node, passive_deletes=True,
    order_by=Node.seq, collection_class=ordering_list('seq'),
    primaryjoin=and_(and_(foreign(Node.hierarchy_id) == Hierarchy.id,
                        Node.group_id == Hierarchy.group_id),
                    Node.parent_id == None))

Node.parent = relationship(
    Node, backref=backref(
        'children', passive_deletes=True,
        order_by=Node.seq, collection_class=ordering_list('seq')),
    primaryjoin=and_(foreign(Node.parent_id) == remote(Node.id),
                    Node.group_id == remote(Node.group_id)))
```

The structure is:

- a group owns many hierarchies
- a hierarchy owns many nodes (where `node.parent_id is NULL`; this is a [filtering primary join](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html#backref-arguments))
- a node owns many nodes (where `node.parent_id = remote(node.parent_id)`)
- all nodes have a link to both their group and hierarchy, even if they are not directly owned by the hierarchy (yes, a little denormalised)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out I was adding the object to the list of children twice. Removing the `node.hierarchy = hierarchy` line fixes the problem. *However*, that's a sub-optimal solution, because I want it to be easy to set the hierarchy of non-root nodes. The real fix is to prevent the `Node.hierarchy` relationship from inserting items into the `Hierarchy.nodes` list. The relationships should be changed to use a one-way backref:

```
Node.hierarchy = relationship(
    Hierarchy,
    primaryjoin=and_(foreign(Node.hierarchy_id) == remote(Hierarchy.id),
                    Node.group_id == remote(Hierarchy.group_id)))

Hierarchy.nodes = relationship(
    Node, back_populates='hierarchy', passive_deletes=True,
    order_by=Node.seq, collection_class=ordering_list('seq'),
    primaryjoin=and_(and_(foreign(Node.hierarchy_id) == Hierarchy.id,
                        Node.group_id == Hierarchy.group_id),
                    Node.parent_id == None))
```

This is described in the docs under [Linking Relationships with Backref > One Way Backrefs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html#one-way-backrefs). As the docs point out, this will also prevent items from being inserted into the `nodes` list even when `Node.parent_id == None`, which is somewhat unfortunate.

I also decided to get rid of the `Hierarchy.nodes_all` relationship, because it was just complicating matters. I'll use a special query if I need that.